# How to I use the ActionBarDrawerToggle Functionality without drawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am using the Android Reside Menu library here:
https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu

Now, the thing is the resideMenu is not a drawer layout but I want the actionBarDrawerToggle functionality. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ActionBarDrawerToggle without a DrawerLayout, so you must create a class extending from DrawerLayout and @Override the openDrawer method. I use an instance of the parent activity

```
package com.bonopark.*.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.bonopark.*.*.HomeActivity;

public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    private HomeActivity ha;

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setParent(HomeActivity ha) {
        this.ha = ha;
    }

    @Override
    public void openDrawer(View view) {
        /* super.openDrawer(view); */
        // do whatever ..
    }

    @Override
    public void closeDrawer(View view) {
        super.closeDrawer(view);
    }
}
```

This custom DrawerLayout must be called on XML files by this form:

```
<com.bonopark.*.*.libs.CustomDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add below in your Toolbar

```
    app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

add below in your activity

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == android.R.id.home)
       {
          yourResideMenu.getResideMenu().openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```